# PHP error: "syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'"

Tags: php, syntax-error

I got this message 
(syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';')
when I was trying to run the following code:

```
 <html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>
 <title>Num One Website</title>

 <?
 $con = mysql_connect("","","");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db("", $con);

 $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Students") ;

 echo "<form action='ConfirmEnter.php' method='post'>";
 echo "<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="mt">"."MidTerm<br>";
 echo "<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="pr">"."Project<br>";
 echo "<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="fi">"."Final<br>";
 echo "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<th>ID</th>";
 echo "<th>MidTerm</th>"; 
 echo "<th>Project</th>"; 
 echo "<th>Final</th>";
 echo "<th>Total</th>". "</tr>";

 $count=1;

 while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
  { 
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input name='ID[]' readonly='readonly' value='". $row1['ID'] ."'      size=5/></td> "; 
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='mt[]' size=5 value='0.0' /></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='pr[]' size=5 value='0.0' /></td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' name='fi[]' size=5 value='0.0' /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 $count++;
  } 
 echo "</table>"; 
 echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />";
 echo "</form>"; 
 mysql_close($con);


 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The error in these lines:

```
 echo "<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="mt">"."MidTerm<br>";
 echo "<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="pr">"."Project<br>";
 echo "<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="fi">"."Final<br>";
```

I looked for this problem in your website and other websites but I couldn't find the solution for it.

Comment: Try not to write in all caps. It's like yelling.

Comment: Why did you decide to use double quotes for those three lines and then use single quotes for all the other lines?

Comment: You could avoid the whole problem by using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s.

Answer (score 7):

Here your syntax is off. use single quotes like you did in your form tag, or escape the double quotes

```
echo "<input type=\"Radio\" name=\"mark\" value=\"mt\">"."MidTerm<br>";
...
...
```

and you need to fix this line too, here:

```
echo "<table border=\"3\" cellpadding=\"3\">";
```

also, you can get by without, but you should quote your `size` values too towards the bottom

Answer (score 2):

`echo "<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="mt">"."MidTerm<br>";`

Escape the Double quotes

`echo "<input type=\"Radio\" name=\"mark\" value=\"mt\">"."MidTerm<br>";`

similarly for other lines.

======

alternatively use single quotes in one of the places.

`echo '<input type="Radio" name="mark" value="mt">'.'MidTerm<br>';`

OR

`echo "<input type='Radio' name='mark' value='mt'>"."MidTerm<br>";`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you have an error? You're not escaping quotes in the string, of course it's not going to work. Just add a `\` before the `"` in the `<input>` tag and you're all good.